# Two carousels on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, themes, carousel

I have a website that wasn't developed by me, it is a wordpress theme and I'm not sure how to do this, as I need to change the code.
The theme comes with one carousel on the homepage called from a php template part. What I need is to have two carousels instead of one.

This is the site: http://tehar.com.br/

As you guys can see, the website is actually with two carousels but they are not working, since I guess the usage of both in the same time causes the javascript to conflict.

I wasn't able to find any javascript call on the page file, and even the .js file that handles the carousel.
Any guess of what to do? I really don't have **any** clue on what to do.

Thanks!

Comment: make a carousel on your own , best idea. YOU WILL LEARN A LOT TO !!

Comment: The documentation for the slider is here: http://revolution.themepunch.com/documentation/

Comment: @IngviJónasson its not the revolution slider, its the carousel that's below the icons...